# function egeri() doesn't work

Tags: php, function, eregi

I have this code but, when I logged in habbo the function doesn't work for the image online, it just shows the image offline:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['habbo'];
$home = file_get_contents("http://www.habbo.com.br/home/".$name);
if (eregi("http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/2245/web-gallery/images/myhabbo/profile/habbo_online_anim.gif", $home))
{
$img = "http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/2245/web-gallery/images/myhabbo/profile/habbo_online.gif";
}
else
{
$img = "http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/2245/web-gallery/images/myhabbo/profile/habbo_offline.gif";
}
header("Content-type: image/gif");
$im = imagecreatefromgif($img);
imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: `eregi()` is deprecated and probably removed from the version of PHP you are using. You need to use `preg_match()` instead (although I suspect regular expressions aren't needed at all and a standard comparison operator will do).

Comment: Yeah, looks like you could use '=='...

Comment: Warning : This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: Who i use that guys?? thanks for help me, i'm a noob. Sorry :(

Comment: functions like ereg, eregi, split etc. are deprecated (not only deprecated, but completely removed) as of PHP 5.3. Read more http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php

Comment: Exactly **WHY** are you tryign to grab a remote gif, decompress it in memory, then re-compress to gif? That's a TOTAL waste of system resources. you could just have `readfile($img);` and skip ALL of that `image*()` stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['habbo'];
$home = file_get_contents('http://www.habbo.com.br/home/'.$habbo);
if (stristr($home, 'http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/2245/web-gallery/images/myhabbo/profile/habbo_online_anim.gif') == TRUE)
{
    $img = 'http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/2245/web-gallery/images/myhabbo/profile/habbo_online.gif';
}
    else
{
    $img = 'http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/2245/web-gallery/images/myhabbo/profile/habbo_offline.gif';
}
header('Content-type: image/gif');
$im = imagecreatefromgif($img);
imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

**stristr** acts like **eregi** when you're not using regexp, this should find the string and compare if it's TRUE or FALSE.

**Update:** '=== TRUE' to '== TRUE'

Comment: I tried this too, but doesn't work, i'm online but appears the image offline, may be this problem is 'cause the code doesn't get the file contents ???

Comment: Test it, first check if the code is getting "anything", then you can eliminating one thing at a time...

Comment: Just tested here, and it's working, just replace '=== TRUE' for '!== FALSE'... Check it: https://www.enginesistemas.com.br/habbo.php

Comment: I just need a code if i'm online appears a online image and if i have offline appears a offline image.

Comment: Check the link I've posted. I just changed the TRUE/FALSE and created a $var to check with STRISTR.

Comment: yes, appears online but in my not, check it: http://testesfods.comze.com/status.php?habbo=Deposito-Nando and i use that:
if (stristr($home, 'http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/2245/web-gallery/images/myhabbo/profile/habbo_online_anim.gif') !== FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`eregi` is depreciated as of PHP 5.3](https://www.php.net/eregi) to 5.4 and completely removed in PHP 5.5. But that said, looking at your code it makes no sense why `eregi` is there to begin with. Look at this line:

```
if (eregi("http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/2245/web-gallery/images/myhabbo/profile/habbo_online_anim.gif", $home))
```

What exactly is the pattern matching that is happening? I seems like it is a simple `==` check to me.  So I would suggest trying this. I am also cleaning up your formatting as well for readability:

```
$name = $_GET['habbo'];

$home = file_get_contents("http://www.habbo.com.br/home/".$name);

$check = "http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/2245/web-gallery/images/myhabbo/profile/habbo_online_anim.gif";

if ($check == $home) {
  $img = "http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/2245/web-gallery/images/myhabbo/profile/habbo_online.gif";
}
else {
  $img = "http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/2245/web-gallery/images/myhabbo/profile/habbo_offline.gif";
}

header("Content-type: image/gif");

$im = imagecreatefromgif($img);

imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: I tested it now, but doesn't work yet, i don't understand 'cause if u use just ($check = $home) i  get the image online but if i use ($check == $home) i get the image offline but i'm online!

Comment: $check = $home would set the value of $check to the value of $home and then return true for doing so. So, it'll always be true. $check == $home would see if $check is the same thing as $home. Check out [comparison operators](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in php.

Comment: I tried but just appears the image offline, never the online!!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

First, [eregi](https://www.php.net/eregi) is deprecated in favor of [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) using the case-insensitive regular expression marker (i). So, you should switch to using preg_match in this and future cases in which a regular expression match needs to be made.

Second, eregi and preg_match don't return boolean values. So, you're going to need to use the identity operator (=== or !==) to test for matches.

Lastly, it's highly unlikely that a match will ever be made, since you're not using a regular expression in your search. You need to be doing something like this:

```
if (eregi('/someregex/i', $home) !== FALSE){
```

It may be helpful for you to review the syntax for PCRE-style regular expressions, which can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php), as well as check the return values for the functions you're using. There's a note on php.net about checking returns using the identity operator.

It seems that you're just searching for a username, in which case it may make more sense to search via [stripos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php), as it's much faster than a regular expression, and searches only for string literals, as you seem to be doing:

```
$name = $_GET['habbo'];
$home = file_get_contents("http://www.habbo.com.br/home/" . $name);
if (stripos($home, "<whatever you're searching for>") !== FALSE) {
```

Either way, you need to check what you're actually searching for. Currently, you seem to be searching for the path leading to that image within the contents of the $home. Unless that complete string is present, you're not going to find it. If you're just searching for habbo_online_anim.gif within $home, try this:

```
if (stripos($home, 'habbo_online_anim.gif') !== FALSE) {
```